# I want tot install maven for using a software call GROBID

Tags: python, maven, installation, grobid

I tried to install maven onm win 10 based on 
https://maven.apache.org/install.html

for installation of software GROBID_NER

https://grobid-ner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build-and-install/

BUT UNFORTUNATELY I faced with this error, can anyone tell me how can I prceed?

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project grobid-ner: Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_211\..\lib\tools.jar -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I think it is related to my jdk, I simply add a path of JDK to my envourement as mentioned in the first link, did a made any mistake?

Comment: Looks like you are using a JRE instead of a JDK.

Comment: I put jdk in my environmental variable.  ```C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211```

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved, I just uninstalled Jdk and Installed the correct version  by a you tube tutorial, since you need to define a new variable in your envourement variable